# Is there any way to get webhook requests when category is newly added or updated or even deleted in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a woocommerce store and I am trying to create a webhook to get notified on category creation/updation/deletion. But, my current version of woocommerce doesn't have any webhook topics that are related to category. My woocommerce version is `7.0.0`

[image]

And my WordPress version is `6.0.2`
[image]

But, in the topics dropdown, there is a value called `Action`
[image]

and when choosing it, I am getting one more input field called `Action event`
[image]

I have tried some custom action topics based on this below woocommerce documentation link

[https://woo.com/document/webhooks/#:~:text=Topic%3A%20Indicate%20when,of%20woocommerce_webhook_topic_hooks%20filter](https://woo.com/document/webhooks/#:%7E:text=Topic%3A%20Indicate%20when,of%20woocommerce_webhook_topic_hooks%20filter)

I tried the below custom action topics

- category_created
- category_added
- woocommerce_admin_product_cat_created
- woocommerce_admin_product_cat_updated
- create_category
- update_category
- create_product_cat
- update_product_cat

But, none of them are triggering any requests to the given Delivery URL.

I wanted to get some webhook requests when there is some action happening on woocommerce category. I am also not sure whether this custom action topic will be supported in the latest versions.

Is there any custom action topic available to achieve these that I have missed? If not, is there any way to get notified when a category is added/deleted/updated in real time or almost real time?